# Open Graph Beta, Display another string in Custom Action Caption using Text Templates if Object Property is null?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

How can we display a different string in a custom action caption using [text templates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/define-units/#captions) or formatters if a `Profile` property is null?

Facebook displays a default caption for an action if a string property is not set or is empty.

For example, a caption for an action with a `Profile` object, `Cooked with {SomeProfile}`, displays the profile's description or something else if `SomeProfile` is not defined.

**Another example**

I have an `Cook` action type. `Cook` is connected to a `Profile` object type. `Cook` has another `Profile` action property `SomeoneICookedWith`. I set the caption for `Cook` to `I cooked this with {SomeoneICookedWith}`.

If `SomeoneICookedWith` is not empty and set to URL to John's profile, the caption on the timeline displays `I cooked this with John`.

If `SomeoneICookedWith` is empty, the caption on the timeline displays `John is on Facebook. Join Facebook to connect with John and others you may know. Facebook gives people the power to share and makes the world more open and connected.`.

Answer (score 0):

It displays the `og:description` of the object if the action is aggregated or if the News Feed attachment isn't configured.

If you are trying to link directly to a Facebook profile, you can't control the `og:description`. I would recommend making proxy pages with your own metatags that just redirect users but then you control the tags instead of us.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the og:description tag doesn't seem to be working with the og beta. The linter grabs my the description and my other custom object properties just fine, but when actually posting them, the only thing that shows up is the image, link, and the title. Description and everything else are left off, and the default 'Description' shows up. I'm beating my head against a wall since the Linter says it's working fine but it's not in actuality.

Paul's answer sounds ideal, but if you redirect the page, then Facebook follows the redirect and grabs the tags from the redirected page. Has anyone else run into this, and what's a good solution?

Comment: Redirect if the user agent is not the Facebook crawler user agent ("facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)" last time I checked). That way the Facebook crawler sees your page that just has your custom metatags, but any actual users who go to that page get redirected to the "normal" page.